# PHP - MySQL syntax error (How to fix?)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to create tables based on a id that changes but i get a syntax error returned:

> FAIL2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 ( myID varchar(255), Data varchar(255), Related varchar(255), )' at line 1

```
@mysql_select_db('mydb'); // Connect to database

// Create Table
$tl = $myID[1];
$sqltable = $tl[0]; // Get first char from id

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $sqltable(myID varchar(255),Data varchar(255),Related varchar(255));";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval ) {
  die('FAIL2: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "DONE<br>";
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: `Data` is a [resrved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks.

Comment: table names can't just be a number which `$sqltable` is, also a table name made of just one character !!!!

Comment: Why are you trying to create a table called `5`?  For one thing, SQL doesn't allow that.  More to the point, that sounds like an open invitation for ambiguity in future queries.

Comment: Obligatory comment on how the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and how important for the security of yourself, your server and your country it is to use `mysqli_*` and prepared statements instead.

Comment: Ok thank, basically i am fairly new to using MySQL and was not aware that you couldn't have short 1 char tables or ones that start with a number. That explains the errors, thanks :D

Comment: @zeddex you can have one char table names, just not names made of only digits, but one char names are not recommended because they're ambiguous and will make the DB admins job harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, by way of example using mysqli_**

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'test');
/* check connection */ 
if (!$link) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
$sqltable = 1234;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$sqltable}` (
        `myID` varchar(255),
        `Data_` varchar(255),
        `Related` varchar(255)
       );"
 );
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
   echo "failure";
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

- In that case you cannot use a prepared statements in the table name,
  prepared statements only allow parameters to be bound to SQL statement , the table name is not one of those runtime values, as it determines the validity of the SQL statement itself  and changing it at execution time would potentially alter the SQL statement that was valid.
- Now,you should have a whitelist of table names that you check against first if the variable $sqltable is coming from user input in order to avoid sql injection.
- Change the column 'Data', it is a reserverd word in MySQL

Comment: Thanks this is useful